# cURL command to Jenkins API in gitlab-ci file is dropping parameters

Tags: curl, jenkins, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to do a cURL command in my gitlab-ci file on a Jenkins' API endpoint to start a job, but no matter what I try the second parameter always gets dropped.  Here is my gitlab-ci file:

```
selenium_test:
  stage: run_test
  tags:
    - autotest1
  only:
    - trigger
  script:
    - jenkins_response=$(curl -s -I -X POST http://user:token@localhost:8080/job/qTest/buildWithParameters?environment=CI%20Dev&test_id=96)
```

With the code above, the `test_id=96` gets dropped.  If I reverse the order of the parameters like so `test_id=96&environment=CI%20Dev` then the `environment=CI%20Dev` gets dropped.

I've also tried encoding the entire string like so `environment%3DCI%20Dev%26test_id%3D96` but that didn't work either.

The two Jenkins' parameters, test_id and environment, are configured in Jenkins as strings.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try escaping & as well (not only space) or putting full url in double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

You are not escaping shell special character (&). Consider following two snippets:

- `curl http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?status=200&body=ALLOK` which will drop second argument and return `None` and
- `curl "http://urlecho.appspot.com/echo?status=200&body=ALLOK"` which will interpret second argument and return proper `ALLOK` response.

You have two options: to enclose full url in double quotes or to escape & like you did with space character in your example. Consider following suggestion from [cURL documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> > when invoked from a command line prompt, you probably have to put the full URL within double quotes to avoid the shell from interfering with it. This also goes for other characters treated special, like for example '&', '?' and '*'.

Comment: This was it.  Thanks so much for your help!