# Jenkinsfile are not called by build

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have Jenkins connected with GitLab, both installed by Helm Chart:

```
helm install stable/jenkins \
  -n jenkins \
  --namespace jenkins \
  --set master.serviceType=ClusterIP \
  --set master.ingress.enabled=true \
  --set master.ingress.hostName=jenkins.example.com \
  --set 'master.ingress.tls[0].secretName=jenkins.tls-secret' \
  --set 'master.ingress.tls[0].hosts={jenkins.example.com}' \
  --set agent.image=brunowego/jnlp-slave-s2i \
  --set agent.tag=3.29-1 \
  --set 'agent.volumes[0].type=HostPath' \
  --set 'agent.volumes[0].hostPath=/var/run/docker.sock' \
  --set 'agent.volumes[0].mountPath=/var/run/docker.sock'

helm install gitlab/gitlab \
  -n gitlab-ce \
  --namespace gitlab \
  --set global.edition=ce \
  --set global.hosts.domain=example.com \
  --set global.hosts.registry.name=registry.gitlab.example.com \
  --set global.hosts.minio.name=minio.gitlab.example.com \
  --set global.ingress.configureCertmanager=false \
  --set global.ingress.class=nginx \
  --set global.ingress.tls.secretName=gitlab.tls-secret \
  --set certmanager.install=false \
  --set nginx-ingress.enabled=false \
  --set gitlab-runner.install=false
```

When I push to git, the build process are started, but the file `Jenkinsfile` not being used:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building...'
            }
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

I have installed plugins like `gitlab-plugin:1.5.12` and `kubernetes-cd:2.1.2`.

Perhaps need explicit that need use `Jenkinsfile` in a configuration?

Comment: Another info is that I disabled native CI/CD from GitLab with `global.appConfig.defaultProjectsFeatures.builds: false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a mistake selecting the freestyle option.

[image: jenkins pipeline option]

After delete the job and recreated with Pipeline option selected, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have documentation about [*migrating* from Jenkins](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jenkins/), it is not a surprise to see a Jenkinsfile is *not* called from a `gitlab-ci.yml` directive file.

For that, your gitlab-ci file should include a curl to the Jenkins server, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51526363/6309)

```
...
script:
    - jenkins_response=$(curl -s -I -X POST "http://user:token@localhost:8080/job/qTest/buildWithParameters?param1=val1")
```